# Cannot proxy requests in python using requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests, proxies

I'm trying to build a basic proxy checker utility in python. This is what I have right now:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
currentip=""
originalip=""
isProxied=False

proxies=["104.236.54.196:8080", "187.62.191.3:61456", "138.204.179.162:44088", "91.216.66.70:32306"]
proxy_count = len(proxies)

url = "https://www.ipchicken.com/"
r = requests.get(url)

def statement():
    global currentip
    global originalip
    print("Current ip is: "+currentip)
    print("Your true ip is: "+originalip)



def main(req):
    global currentip
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
    html = soup.html
    body = html.body
    font = body.find_all('font')
    ip_container = font[0].b
    ip = ip_container.contents[0]
    currentip=ip

main(r)

originalip=currentip

statement()

print("\n\n")

print("testing proxies...")

print("\n\n")

for x in range(proxy_count):
    proxyContainer={"http":"http://"+proxies[x]}
    r2 = requests.get(url, proxies=proxyContainer, timeout=20)
    print("proxy: " + proxies[x])
    main(r2)
    statement()
    print("\n\n")
    if (currentip==originalip): 
        print("Proxy failed.")
    else:
        print("This proxy works")
    print("\n")
```

The code runs fine and the requests are made, but they seem to not be proxied. Here is my output:

```
Current ip is: 
199.229.249.163
Your true ip is: 
199.229.249.163



testing proxies...



proxy: 104.236.54.196:8080
Current ip is: 
199.229.249.163
Your true ip is: 
199.229.249.163



Proxy failed.


proxy: 187.62.191.3:61456
Current ip is: 
199.229.249.163
Your true ip is: 
199.229.249.163



Proxy failed.


proxy: 138.204.179.162:44088
Current ip is: 
199.229.249.163
Your true ip is: 
199.229.249.163



Proxy failed.


proxy: 91.216.66.70:32306
Current ip is: 
199.229.249.163
Your true ip is: 
199.229.249.163



Proxy failed.
```

I have tested these proxies in a separate program and they seem to work fine, I don't think the proxies are the issue.

Comment: if you connect to  encrypted url `https` then you should set proxy for encrypted `https` or `ssl` connection - but you set proxy only for `http`

Comment: instead of using `global` in `main()` you should use `return ip` and `currentip = main(r)`

Answer (score 1):

If you connect to encrypted url `https` then you have to set proxy for `https` connections but you set proxy only for `http` so it doesn't use proxy.

Problem is to find working proxy.

I took from https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/?type=s#list but I don't know how long it will work.

And to test IP I used httpbin.org which returns data as JSON so it is easy to display or convert to Python's dictionary.

```
import requests 

url = "https://httpbin.org/ip"

proxies = {
   #"http": '141.125.82.106:80',
   "https": '141.125.82.106:80',
}

r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)

print(r.text)

ip = r.json()["origin"]
print('IP:', ip)
```

---

**BTW:** other problem can be that some proxy sends your IP in extra header and servers may get it - so not all proxies are anonymouse.

---

**EDIT:** Version with https://www.ipchicken.com/

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_ip(request):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "html.parser")
    return soup.find('font').b.contents[0]

url = "https://www.ipchicken.com/"

proxies = {
   #"http": '141.125.82.106:80',
   "https": '141.125.82.106:80',
}

r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
ip = get_ip(r)
print(ip)
```